# .h file cannot see another in the same folder C++ Eclipse

Tags: c++, header, include, eclipse-cdt

The weird thing about this problem is that other .cpp and .h files can find the file but not this one, they're all in the SAME folder. My file structure is as follows:

/Entity.h // is being included

/Graphics.cpp // can include

/Graphics.h // CANNOT include

/main.cpp // can include

/Physics.cpp // can include

/Physics.h // can include

Graphics.cpp, main.cpp, Physics.cpp, Physics.h are all able to include Entity.h but Graphics.h cannot.

This is Entity.h

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H

#include <vector>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct entity
{
    int ID;
    vector<long double> position;
    vector<long double> velocity;
    vector<long double> acceleration;
    sf::Color colour;
    sf::CircleShape selfImage;
    long double mass;
};

entity createEntity(long double x, long double y, long double xV, long double yV, long double m, int newID)
{
    entity e;
    // assign entity ID and increment entity ID count
    e.ID = newID;

    // initialise velocity, acceleration & position to 0
    e.position.resize(2, 0);
    e.velocity.resize(2, 0);
    e.acceleration.resize(2, 0);

    e.position = {x, y};
    e.velocity = {xV, yV};

    // setup self-image
    e.colour = sf::Color (255, 0, 0);
    e.selfImage.setFillColor(e.colour);

    // initialise mass
    e.mass = m;

    return e;
};


#endif // ENTITY_H
```

This is Graphics.h

```
/*
 * Graphics.h
 *
 *  Created on: 26 Mar 2019
 *      Author: chris
 */
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H_
#define GRAPHICS_H_

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <Entity.h>

class Graphics
{
    public:
        Graphics(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT);
        ~Graphics();
        void update(vector<entity> entities);

        int W_WIDTH;
        int W_HEIGHT;
        sf::RenderWindow window;

};



#endif /* GRAPHICS_H_ */
```

Physics.h, an example of something which can include Entity.h

```
#ifndef PHYSICS_H
#define PHYSICS_H

#include <Entity.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class Physics
{
    long double G_CONST = 0.00000000006674;
    public:
        Physics();
        virtual ~Physics();

        const int MAP_WIDTH = 1000;
        const int MAP_HEIGHT = 1000;

        vector<vector<entity*>> gameMap;
        vector<entity> entityList;

        void addEntity(entity e);
        int update();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // PHYSICS_H
```

The console output is the following

```
make all 
Building file: ../Graphics.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Graphics.d" -MT"Graphics.o" -o "Graphics.o" "../Graphics.cpp"
In file included from ../Graphics.cpp:7:
../Graphics.h:12:10: fatal error: ./Entity.h: No such file or directory
 #include <./Entity.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [subdir.mk:26: Graphics.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

I am using Eclipse on Debian. This has me puzzled, I cannot see a difference in the files.

EDIT:
using "" instead of <> around the include statements file name fixed the problem. Other problems have ensued however :((((((

Comment: Have you changed your include path?

Comment: nope, i’ve just created a CDT project in Eclipse and away I went. I did add SFML’s include folder to /usr/include but apart from that, no

Comment: I would try without the `./` before `Entity.h`

Comment: Maybe you have more than 1 `Graphics.h` files that are in different folders.

Comment: How did you include Graphics.h? Using <> or "" ?

Comment: In addition to drescherjm: I roughly remember that providing a header with same name in multiple include paths, the compiler will consider the order of include path (arguments) to search for first match. I cannot remember that this yields any error. I'm not sure whether this is granted - normally, I really try to prevent this. ;-)

Comment: Yet another hint: Usually, I prefix all my own sources with some kind of abbreviation for our S/W. General names like "Graphics", "Physics", etc. are IMHO an invitation for accidental matches from other libraries. The use of `#include ""` (with quotes) forces the compiler to consider the current path first when searching the included file - another thing to prevent wrong matches.

Comment: @dresscherjm i have tried ./ which did not help, i should’ve specified, will edit post. Scheff I will use the naming convention as that seems to be a potential solution and i will remove all other include paths when i am back at my pc. Thank you both for the responses

Comment: @Scheff well that fixed that error but now it's not finding the .so files that i linked when they are 100% there with the line like this /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/chris/Programs/lib/SFML-2.5.1/lib/libsfml-window.so

Comment: Not finding an include file is a compiler issue. Include paths could be the reason or (like in your case) wrong files in wrong folders. `/usr/bin/ld` is a link issue. There are similar reasons (missing library paths, wrong object files or libraries in wrong folders). Shared objects (`.so`) are somehow special. On one hand, you might have to note them in link command, on the other hand, linking happens strictly speaking at start time of application. (It's a bit confusing.) Please, research regarding this, or open a new question. (I must admit I'm not an expert in link issues on Linux.)

Comment: @Scheff, I searched around on Google but solutions I found didn't help very much. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :) programming has never been so temperamental before ugh